# 2GP dependent managed package creation failing with null explanation message

Tags: salesforcedx, 2gp, ancestor

I have an `sfdx-project.json` of this form that worked about  week ago to create an unpublished version of a package that depends on another package:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            ...
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "MyPackage@1.19.0.2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ...
    "packageAliases": {
        "MyPackage@1.19.0.2": "04t***************"
    }
}
```

but today (26 Jan 2022) the `sfdx:force:package:version:create` fails repeatedly this error:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Multiple errors occurred:
(1) An error occurred while trying to install a package dependency,
    ID 04t************: null
(2) An error occurred while trying to install a package dependency,
    ID 04t************: null
```

Changing the dependency to an earlier version generates the corresponding error for that. I've updated to the latest CLI `from 7.133.0-cddd46d to 7.134.0-4f69b20`.

Anyone else experiencing this or have a solution? I note that I'm also getting this new message from SFDX:

> Warning: Based on feedback from Salesforce Partners, we’re enhancing
> the package ancestry feature. Starting in Spring ‘22, the ancestor
> version field is required when you create a package version. Look for
> more details, including how to override the ancestry requirement, in
> the packaging section of the Spring ‘22 Salesforce Release Notes and
> in the Salesforce DX Developer Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the cause is "operator error". I was missing:

```
--definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json
```

from my `sfdx:force:package:version:create` and so was not turning on the features in the packaging org that the depended on package needs. Hence its installation was failing, albeit with just `null` output as the reason message rather than something more helpful.